# GeoLocation and Camera not working on `meteor run ios`

Tags: ios, meteor

I downloaded a sample repo from [Meteor's GitHub](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages) and ran the three example apps without changing any of the code. They all work in Chrome but none of them work in iOS simulator. Neither GeoLocation or Camera works, though it did prompt me to give location permission (which I allowed). Below are some screenshots. Can anyone help me get it working? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've play with that app time ago and it wasn't working on my Android phone, I didn't  investigate too much so I'm not sure of my answer but I always thought that was related to google API key. Try to log your position to see if the problem is related to geolocation package or if it's a problem with google map.